# How can I change the font size in Android Studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, button, text-size

I don't want to change the font size of Android Studio itself, but rather the font size of the app i'm working on. All the search results I have found talk about the user interface or zooming in.

I'm Working on a tic-tac-toe beginner project and the button text always is so small. Any tips on how to increase it?

Here is its part in the xml file:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

[image: Click to see the image]

Many thanks in advance for anyone who helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:textSize` property into `Button`, eg:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button_0"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 />
```

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:textSize

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change the textSize attribute in the XML file. The other way is to mention it in the program.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button_0);
btn.setTextSize(20.0f);
```

where *btn* is the name of the button.

**Note: The size mentioned in the setTextSize() method must be a float value.**